# Jquery .animate not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

My Developer and I are stuck on getting this JavaScript working for the lead form on the homepage and others.

http://nextinlinefilms.com.au/index.php here is the link. It is the "make an enquiry today" image that when you click on "Click Here" the form should slide down and show.

Here is the code:

```
$( ".jscript" ).click(function() {   
$( ".enquiry" ).animate({height: "auto"},500);   
});
```

Which says when the class "jscript" is clicked, animate the form class "enquiry" and make height auto

The code should be right!?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: You have a conflict with mootools on the same page. Use `jQuery` instead of `$`, so that you will have `jQuery('.jscript').click(...`, the same for animation.

Comment: We changed it and it still isnt working 

jQuery( ".jscript" ).click(function() {   
jQuery( ".enquiry" ).animate({height: "auto"},500);   
});

Comment: Now it does not show an error related to the .click 'property'. It does not work because of your animation. Do you want to hide? Why not to do just `$( ".enquiry" ).slideUp();` Or do you want to change the height to show the included form? Try to use `100%` instead of `auto`, I remember there were some problems with its animation.

Comment: Try `jQuery( ".enquiry" ).animate({height:'100%'}, 500);` for the auto - check google for `jquery animate auto`

Comment: Except the fact that it does not animate it, just shows it. I think it is related to the fixed height which is animated to the 100%.

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: The best way is to set the final height manually, otherwise google 'jquery animate 100%'. There is a problem with calculation of the final height, that is why jquery is not able to calculate it correctly.

Comment: Or you can try something like this.. Make a copy of element, hide it, insert and calculate it height..remove it, apply this height for animation. http://jsfiddle.net/o1k83aa9/ Do not guarantee that it will work in any situation.

Comment: Got it to open and close with px but I know on phones and that the height is different got to get the 100% working and work out the height issue. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Is the .jscript element created by javascript, or hardcoded in html, because a lot of the times, the problem here is that the element doesn't exist when you use the selector for onclick, and it doesn't work so try this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("parentOfjscript").on("click", ".jscript", function() { //parentOfjscript being some parent element containing jscript
        $(".enquiry").animate({height: "auto"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Make sure that the parent element of .jscript is an element that already exists in the dom, before this selection click function is created on the page.